# Need help verifying my proof that $(\mathbb{Z}, s)$ admits quantifier elimination

Tags: proof-verification, model-theory

So I was hoping to get some help verifying my proof that $(\mathbb{Z}, s)$ admits quantifier elimination. I am hoping to use this to get a 'feel' for these sorts of proofs and theorem.

My attempt is to use the following theorem in David Marker's book.

"Let $T$ be a $L$-theory. Suppose for every quantifier-free, $\theta(\bar v, w)$, there is a quantifier-free $\psi(\bar v)$ such that $T\models\exists w\ \theta(\bar v, w)\leftrightarrow \psi(\bar v)$, then $T$ admits quantifier elimination"

So all we have to show is that Th($\mathbb{Z}$) in the language consisting of only the succesor function, $s$, can eliminate a single existential quantifier. I would like to induct on $\theta(\bar v, w)$ minus the quantifer case.

So for atomic case: We have $\mathbb{Z} \models \exists b\ s^n(x) = s^m(b)$, for the forward implication we can let it be the tautology $s^n(x) = s^n(x)$. For the backward implication, $s^n(x) = s^n(x) \rightarrow \exists b\ s^n(x) = s^m(b)$ because $\mathbb{Z}$ has no end points, we can always find some guy to the left of (any) $x$ and 'reach it'.

After the atomic case, if nothing goes wrong, the Induction hypothesis should get us through the inductive step.

So is my attempt valid ? If it is wrong, any hints to point me in the right direction is deeply appreciated.

Cheers !

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, thanks for pointing out. I missed out an existential quantifier

Comment: That is not the only atomic case. Your explanation for that particular case is pretty unclear to me, but seems like it could be right... (it is definitely equivalent to x=x). I don't see how 'the inductive hypothesis should get us through...' that's the kind of thing you need to show. It's not clear to me what form your induction is taking and how the induction hypothesis would be used in, say, the case of a negated formula.